# Blender render result not consistent

Tags: rendering, color

[image]

This is a one-color green cube rendered, no light in scene.
But it has two color mixed instead(try color pick).
Anyway to fix this?

Here is the shader I used for cube.

Comment: In your Render Properties tab, scroll all the way to the bottom where it says "Color Management" and under _View Transform_ try changing from "filmic" to "standard" and see if that helps. It's hard to tell much else without seeing your node setup, any chance you could post a screenshot?

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with *dithering*, i.e. Blender tries to display color that can't be described in a given color space, so, based on some formula involving position, it displays one of neighboring colors in the color space. Can you go to *Output Properties* tab, expand *Post Processing* panel on the very bottom and decrease **dithering** to 0?

Comment: I changed view transform to raw and standard, still has two colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Broady, my problem solved!

Comment: Dithering is useful, so it's still worth to investigate why Blender fails to display the exact color and dithers it.